# How to use absolute file path in liquibase change sets?

Tags: java, liquibase

I have muli moduled maven based application. There are several change sets in each module. I want to write integration tests in one of them. I know it's bad idea but,  i have business log constraints.

In considered module i have code that uses repositories from 2 others modules. During tests i have to initialize tables from change sets in different modules. I don't know how to use absolute path to change sets or how to use liquibase config.

I tried use include or includeAll tags, but in classpath where tests run i can't call change sets out of module.

Hope for your ideas.

Comment: You could use liquibase include tags to point to multiple changeset files. You should be able to give any path from the root of your project http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html

Comment: The point is my changesets not in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to create liquibase instance in your junit by  passing absolute file paths. You can refer liquibase tests in github for more info

```
new Liquibase(changeLogFile, FileSystemResourceAccesor, database);
```

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-integration-tests/src/test/java/liquibase/dbtest/AbstractIntegrationTest.java#L890